# Modifying an object using indexedDb

Tags: indexeddb

I am storing an object in IndexedDB, in the following format.

```
var _object ={
    stud1: { name: 'ABC', surName: 'PQR' },
    stud2: { name: 'zxc', surName: 'ppp' } 
};
```

How do I update the object, so that the `stud1` key would be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question right, you aren't deleting the object, you are *modifying* the object. So you would get the data, modify it, and then put the new version. (See docs for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Updating_an_entry_in_the_database)

Comment: Yes doing the same thing. Thank You